# No improvement in prediction accuracy, in-spite of obtaining best c and g value

Tags: machine-learning, computer-science, libsvm

I am a newbie in machine learning.Hence i apologize in advanced for this silly question.

I used **LIBSVM** to train a scaled training data using default parameter and generated a model. However i got a only 26.26% accuracy on test data. Hence,I used grid search to obtain optimum C and gamma(g) value.

I plugged in the best C and G value and re-trained my training data.But there was no change in accuracy.Can anyone please explain me the reason behind this.Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply the relevant lines of your code, preferably a small fully-contained working code. Of course, if you could also supply the data in question so that the issue can be reproduced, it would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize the data first and then use grid search to obtain optimum C and gamma(g) value.
Remember you need to normalize both training and testing data.